# What strategy to use for a Sencha App build process which uses Cordova/Phonegap and supports multi platform?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, cordova-2.0.0, sencha-touch-2.2

I am developing a Sencha Touch mobile application targeting iOS and Android. It uses Cordova & its plugins.

I really liked the Sencha command line tool for building my application, it bundles all the required JS files into one single JS and also brings down the size of the application considerably. But the problem I am running into is that cordova JS file is platform specific and has to include inside the HTML based on the platform?

So, I Looked at various options of creating a Symbolic link or using Sencha app as a submodule which I understand & works well with raw sencha files. I am not sure how to get it work with the files generated by the Sencha build command.

So, any help in using files generated by Sencha build command along with Cordova / Phonegap and its plugins for each platform would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Brice Mason's [Sencha-cordova-builder](https://github.com/bricemason/sencha-cordova-builder) and [tutorial videos](http://vimeo.com/bricemason/videos) of sencha touch build for iOS & Android

Comment: Thanks! Will check and revert back.

Comment: The above link helped me. But with Cordova 2.9 I am seeing they have their own build process. So, planning to use that